# How to support both IPv4 and IPv6 connections

Tags: c++, winsock, ipv6, sockets, ipv4

I'm currently working on a UDP socket application and I need to build in support so that IPV4 and IPV6 connections can send packets to a server.

I was hoping that someone could help me out and point me in the right direction; the majority of the documentation that I found was not complete. It'd also be helpful if you could point out any differences between Winsock and BSD sockets.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 101, accepted):

The best approach is to create an IPv6 server socket that can also accept IPv4 connections. To do so, create a regular IPv6 socket, turn *off* the socket option `IPV6_V6ONLY`, bind it to the "any" address, and start receiving. IPv4 addresses will be presented as IPv6 addresses, in the [IPv4-mapped](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6#IPv4-mapped_IPv6_addresses) format.

The major difference across systems is whether `IPV6_V6ONLY` is a) available, and b) turned on or off by default. It is turned off by default on Linux (i.e. allowing dual-stack sockets without setsockopt), and is turned on on most other systems.

In addition, the IPv6 stack on Windows XP doesn't support that option. In these cases, you will need to create two separate server sockets, and place them into select or into multiple threads.

Comment: Saying that IPV6_V6ONLY is off by default on Linux is wrong: it depends on the operating system, not just on the kernel. For instance, on Debian GNU/Linux, it recently switched to on by default.

Comment: OS X also has it off by default, but the best thing is to always set it explicitly. The local sysadmin might've changed it after all.

Comment: The default on Windows is enabled (just implemented this on Win7).

Comment: if IPV6_V6ONLY is not available, does it imply that the OS doesn't support dual stacking?

Comment: @Andrius Bentkus: as Windows XP demonstrates, it is well possible to have a system where you can simultaneously use IPv4 and IPv6, yet IPV6_V6ONLY is not available. Whether or not this is "dual stacking" depends on your definition of that term.

Comment: @bortzmeyer I have *Linux Stretch* and [`IPV6_V6ONLY`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2693709/what-was-the-motivation-for-adding-the-ipv6-v6only-flag) is **off** by default (I verified that). Even [`man ipv6`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/ipv6.7.html) specifies that: *The default value for this flag is defined by the contents of the file `/proc/sys/net/ipv6/bindv6only`.  **The default value for that file is 0 (false).*** I think that your post probably referred to one of the old *Linux Debian* release.

Comment: Can you point me to the example source code which supports both IPv4 and IPv6 connections (which parses IPv4-mapped format too)?

Comment: @patryk.beza Debian testing/unstable briefly set the default to 0 in version 4.40 of the netbase package the change was reverted a few months later in version 4.42 of netbase. The change did not make it into any stable release. I guess bortzeyer saw the news about the original change but missed the news of the revert.

Answer (score 9):

The socket API is governed by IETF RFCs and should be the same on all platforms including windows WRT IPv6.

For IPv4/IPv6 applications it's *ALL* about `getaddrinfo()` and `getnameinfo()`.  `getaddrinfo` is a genius - looks at DNS, port names and capabilities of the client to resolve the eternal question of “can I use IPv4, IPv6 or both to reach a particular destination?” Or if you're going the dual-stack route and want it to return IPv4-mapped IPv6 addresses, it will do that too.

It provides a direct `sockaddr *` structure that can be plugged into `bind()`, `recvfrom()`, `sendto()` and the address family for `socket()`… In many cases this means no messy `sockaddr_in(6)` structures to fill out and deal with.

For UDP implementations I would be careful about setting dual-stack sockets or, more generally, binding to all interfaces (`INADDR_ANY`). The classic issue is that, when addresses are not locked down (see `bind()`) to specific interfaces and the system has multiple interfaces requests, responses may transit from different addresses for computers with multiple addresses based on the whims of the OS routing table, confusing application protocols—especially any systems with authentication requirements.

For UDP implementations where this is not a problem, or TCP, dual stack sockets can save a lot of time when IPv*-enabling your system.  One must be careful to not rely entirely on dual-stack where it`s not absolutely necessary as there are no shortage of reasonable platforms (Old Linux, BSD, Windows 2003) deployed with IPv6 stacks not capable of dual stack sockets.

Comment: problem is... the documentation in the manpages about said functions is not clear at all about it 'just' being for ipv4 and ipv6 and it reads like it will give a struct sockaddr for ANY protocol family that has a hostname that resolves to word... also that whole 'hints' thing.. exactly how much of a 'hint' is it. it wasn't a 'hint' it was a 'command' as far as i'm concerned. :P also there is quite a bit of operational risk in it returning a whole lot of ipv6 sockaddr's when ipv6 is enabled on a box one will have to cycle through with connect() timeouts too but doesn't actually route anywhere.

Answer (score 4):

I've been playing with this under Windows and it actually does appear to be a security issue there, if you bind to the loopback address then the IPv6 socket is correctly bound to [::1] but the mapped IPv4 socket is bound to INADDR_ANY, so your (supposedly) safely local-only app is actually exposed to the world.

Answer (score 3):

The RFCs don't really specify the existence of the IPV6_V6ONLY socket option, but, if it is absent, the RFCs are pretty clear that the implementation should be as though that option is FALSE.

Where the option is present, I would argue that it should default FALSE, but, for reasons passing understanding, BSD and Windows implementations default to TRUE.  There is a bizarre claim that this is a security concern because an unknowing IPv6 programmer could bind thinking they were binding only to IN6ADDR_ANY for only IPv6 and accidentally accept an IPv4 connection causing a security problem. I think this is both far-fetched and absurd in addition to a surprise to anyone expecting an RFC-compliant implementation.

In the case of Windows, non-compiance won't usually be a surprise. In the case of BSD, this is unfortunate at best.

Comment: The standard on IPv6 API, RFC 3493, describes IPV6_V6ONLY in its section 5.3 if you want to read all the details.

Answer (score 1):

As Craig M. Brandenburg observes, getaddrinfo does all the heavy lifting to make dual IPv4/IPv6 possible.  I have an experimental server and client on my localhost.  I use this in the server:

```
hints.ai_family = AF_INET6;
hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_DGRAM;
hints.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE;
...
```

The client can then connect to the server using any kind of address:

```
hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;
hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_DGRAM;

host_port = "4950"; // whatever

// All of these work.
host_ip = "127.0.0.1";        // Pure IPv4 address
host_ip = "::ffff:127.0.0.1"; // IPv4 address expressed as IPv6
host_ip = "::1";              // Pure IPv6 address
host_ip = "localhost";        // Domain name

int rv = getaddrinfo(host_ip, host_port, &hints, &result);
...
```