# request.connection.remoteAddress Now Prefixed in ::ffff in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, networking, ip-address

I recently changed my router over to one provided by Google for Google Fiber (yay!) and now I am noticing a change in what I am seeing when I inspect request.connection.remoteAddress while I develop on my local server. Before, I used to see this:

```
request.connection.remoteAddress; // 192.168.1.10
```

Now I am seeing this:

```
request.connection.remoteAddress; // ::ffff:192.168.1.10
```

1. Can anyone explain what is going on?
2. Is my Node server listening to IPv6 addresses?
3. Is `::ffff:192.168.1.10` actually an IPv6 address or is it an IPv4 address?
4. Is the easiest way to tell if a remoteAddress is IPv6 to check if the string contains `::`?
5. When storing IPv4 addresses in the database I used to use something like `INET_ATON` to change them into large integers. Should I abandon this and just store all remote addresses as strings that can be 45 characters long (maximum length of an IPv6 address string)

Answer (score 50, accepted):

> Is my Node server listening to IPv6 addresses?

Yes. Your server is listening to IPv6 connections and the `IPV6_V6ONLY` flag isn't set with the result that IPv4 connections are processed by the same socket. You can read some more about this flag in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2693709/785541).

Whether IPv6 connections are possible (can be routed to your server) is irrelevant in that case - the important thing is that IPv4 connections are received by a socket listening to IPv6 connections.

> Is `::ffff:192.168.1.10` actually an IPv6 address or is it an IPv4 address?

Both. IPv6 addresses can embed IPv4 addresses - and this is one of these embedded addresses. See [IPv4-mapped IPv6 addresses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6#IPv4-mapped_IPv6_addresses).

> Is the easiest way to tell if a remoteAddress is IPv6 to check if the string contains `::`?

An IPv6 address doesn't necessarily contain `::`, it's rather a short notation indicating some number of zeroes. `::ffff:192.168.1.10` is equivalent to `0:0:0:0:0:ffff:192.168.1.10` or `0:0:0:0:0:ffff:c0a8:010a` (see [IPv6 address presentation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6_address#Presentation)). So in order to distinguish IPv6 and IPv4 addresses you should simply check for a single colon - `:`.

> When storing IPv4 addresses in the database I used to use something like INET_ATON to change them into large integers. Should I abandon this and just store all remote addresses as strings that can be 45 characters long (maximum length of an IPv6 address string)

An IPv6 address is a 128-bit number - even if you can store it as a number (e.g. as two `BIGINT` numbers in MySQL), it's questionable whether this approach really makes sense. The only scenario I can think of where you would need to work with numbers is evaluating subnet masks, for everything else a string is sufficient and easier to handle.

Answer (score 15):

re: #4, a library like [ipaddr.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ipaddr.js) works well, e.g.:

```
var ipString = request.connection.remoteAddress;
if (ipaddr.IPv4.isValid(ipString)) {
  // ipString is IPv4
} else if (ipaddr.IPv6.isValid(ipString)) {
  var ip = ipaddr.IPv6.parse(ipString);
  if (ip.isIPv4MappedAddress()) {
    // ip.toIPv4Address().toString() is IPv4
  } else {
    // ipString is IPv6
  }
} else {
  // ipString is invalid
}
```