# Stripping "::ffff:" prefix from request.connection.remoteAddress nodejs

Tags: node.js, express

I am implementing subscription/response possibility using nodejs (express). When visitor send request, beside other parameters within request (port, time interval etc...) I am going to collect ip in order to be able to send response to that ip from time to time.

I am fetching visitor ip address using folowing:

```
  var ip = req.headers['x-forwarded-for'] || 
             req.connection.remoteAddress || 
             req.socket.remoteAddress ||
             req.connection.socket.remoteAddress;
```

based on [How can I get the user's IP address using Node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8107856/how-can-i-get-the-users-ip-address-using-node-js)

Point is that after i get ip I have something like this : "::ffff:192.168.1.10" (explained at [request.connection.remoteAddress Now Prefixed in ::ffff in node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24896386/request-connection-remoteaddress-now-prefixed-in-ffff-in-node-js) )

I am wondering, is it "safe" just to strip "::ffff:" prefix in order to get ip address which I will be able to use in order to reply via http response, or I am missing something else over here, and that is not what i should do?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Yes, it's safe to strip.  Here's a quick way to do it.

```
address.replace(/^.*:/, '')
```

What happens is your OS is listening with a hybrid IPv4-IPv6 socket, which converts any IPv4 address to IPv6, by embedding it within the [IPv4-mapped IPv6 address format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6#IPv4-mapped_IPv6_addresses). This format just prefixes the IPv4 address with `:ffff:`, so you can recover the original IPv4 address by just stripping the `:ffff:`.  (Some deprecated mappings prefix with `::` instead of `:ffff:`, so we use the regex `/^.*:/` to match both forms.)

If you aren't sure that incoming IPv6 address came from an IPv4, you can check that it matches the IPv6-mapping template first:

```
template = /^:(ffff)?:(?!0)(?!.*\.$)((1?\d?\d|25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d)(\.|$)){4}$/
has_ipv4_version = template.test(address)
```

Comment: This isn't remotely safe.  What if you had a legitimate IPv6 address?

Comment: The example address `::ffff:192.168.1.10` *is* legitimate! The question isn't whether the IPv6 address is legitimate; it's whether you can get a legitimate IPv4 address by stripping off the `::ffff:`. And if your OS is automatically generating the IPv6 address from an IPv4 address, then the answer to that question is **yes**.

Comment: Let me rephrase... what if you had an IPv6 address that wasn't a mapped IPv4 address?  Your regex will destroy it.

Comment: The OP specifically said that his/her IPv4 addresses are being remapped to IPv6 due to a hybrid dual-stack IPv6/IPv4 socket (as explained in the [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24896386/request-connection-remoteaddress-now-prefixed-in-ffff-in-node-js) given). Thus there DOES exist a IPv4 address. In general, these [IPv4-mapped IPv6 addresses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6#IPv4-mapped_IPv6_addresses) have a particular format that you can detect if you want a more general algorithm. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Indeed, my question was is this safe thing to do. Additionally @Brad have a point as well. After my research (specifically for my case) stripping was more then enough. I am marking this answer as accepted one having in mind that everything is included - Confirmation, is it safe or not, how to strip it and how to detect is it mapped IPv4 or not in order to avoid issues.

Answer (score 31):

If you want to get the ip address of IPv4, you can use:

```
http.createServer(callback).listen(port, '0.0.0.0');
```

then, you will get what you want

```
req.connection.remoteAddress   // 192.168.1.10
```

Here is the relevant  [document](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v4.x/docs/api/http.html#http_server_listen_port_hostname_backlog_callback) of nodejs

Comment: And this is the only valid answer in the whole topic. What a shame it is not most upvoted. Let me somehow GRAB ATTENTION TO THIS ANSWER. Do not ever parse IP with regexps and string functions!

Comment: I totally disagree. As I mentioned above, the way of picking up the address which will cover all of the cases will have "::ffff:" in front. That is the whole POINT of question. I never asked how can I fetch the IP, instead of that I asked is it safe to strip prefix which is added to it! Even further, above solution will not pick the remote address properly if server is behind the proxy!

Comment: `req.connection.remoteAddress` gives me the same IP-6-extended address (from localhost) as described in the accepted answer: `::ffff:127.0.0.1`. So this answer does not seem to be true anymore.

Answer (score 2):

```
app.post('/xyz',function(request,response)
{
    var IPFromRequest=request.connection.remoteAddress;
    var indexOfColon = IPFromRequest.lastIndexOf(':');
    var IP = IPFromRequest.substring(indexOfColon+1,IPFromRequest.length);
    console.log(IP);
});
```

Comment: var IP = req.connection.remoteAddress.split(":").pop();

Answer (score 2):

I would split the remoteAddress `::ffff:192.168.1.10` by the `:` delimiter and simply take the value of the output array at index `array.length - 1`

like so:

```
const remoteAddress = '::ffff:192.168.0.3'
const array = remoteAddress.split(':')
const remoteIP = array[array.length - 1]
console.log(remoteIP)
```

prints out `192.168.0.3`

Comment: Question was not how to strip it ... (even selected answer covers that as well). It was mostly, "IS IT SAFE TO STRIP IT" and what kind of consequences we can have because of that.

Comment: welp, that's what i get for answering to the wrong stack overflow tab.

Answer (score 1):

This node code ...

returns ipv6 to ipv4 IF the ipv6 address is really a mapped ipv4 address
else it returns a normalised ipv6 address
else it just returns the ip string it originally had

```
var ip = (function (req) {
    var ipaddr = require('ipaddr.js');
    var ipString = (req.headers["X-Forwarded-For"] ||
        req.headers["x-forwarded-for"] ||
        '').split(',')[0] ||
        req.connection.remoteAddress;

    if (ipaddr.isValid(ipString)) {
        try {
            var addr = ipaddr.parse(ipString);
            if (ipaddr.IPv6.isValid(ipString) && addr.isIPv4MappedAddress()) {
                return addr.toIPv4Address().toString();
            }
            return addr.toNormalizedString();
        } catch (e) {
            return ipString;
        }
    }
    return 'unknown';
}(req));
```

https://www.npmjs.com/package/ipaddr.js

https://github.com/whitequark/ipaddr.js

Comment: based on third party script "ipaddr.js" ? Can you please provide a github link?

Comment: links added hope that helps

Comment: Caution... your code blindly trusts any upstream `X-Forwarded-For` headers.  If you're using Express, you can use it's "trust proxy" feature to handle this for you.  Otherwise, you must do it.  Also, the headers are always lower-case so you don't need to check for both.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add onto the answer provided by Michael Matthew Toomim,

If you want to test to see if the IP **is** an IPv4 address mapped as an IPv6, you will probably want to adjust the regex to this:

```
/^:{1,2}(ffff)?:(?!0)(?!.*\.$)((1?\d?\d|25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d)(\.|$)){4}$/
```

The difference being `/^:{1,2}` instead of `/^:`, which allows for both addresses which start with `::ffff:` and `:ffff:`.

Answer (score -2):

Had the same problem...im also new at javascript but i solved this with .slice

```
var ip = req.connection.remoteAddress;

if (ip.length < 15) 
{   
    ip = ip;
}
else
{
    var nyIP = ip.slice(7);
    ip = nyIP;
}
```

Comment: var ip = req.connection.remoteAddress;if (ip.length >= 15) ip = ip.slice(7);

Answer (score -3):

req.connection.remoteAddress.substring(7,req.connection.remoteAddress.length)