# Can't turn off socket option IPV6_V6ONLY

Tags: c, macos, sockets

I'm trying to [turn off the socket option IPV6_V6ONLY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1618240/how-to-support-both-ipv4-and-ipv6-connections).

```
int no = 0;     
setsockopt(fd, IPPROTO_IPV6, IPV6_V6ONLY, (void *)&no, sizeof(no));
```

**Why does the above fail with errno 22 (EINVAL)?**

This is on OS X. It also doesn't work when `no` is 1. Setting other socket options works, for example

```
int yes = 1;
setsockopt(fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, (void *)&yes, sizeof(yes));
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What did your call to `socket()` look like for `fd`?  If the first parameter, the protocol family, wasn't `AF_INET6` (or `PF_INET6`), then this call isn't applicable.

Answer (score 9):

It looks like *BSD derived OS doesn't allow set nor clear this option.
I see the same behavior on FreeBSD 8.X. The socket is 100% AF_INET6.

Comment: FreeBSD since 5.x has disabled IPv4 mapped on IPv6 addresses and thus unless you turn that feature back on by setting the required configuration flag in rc.conf you won't be able to use it.

Answer (score 6):

Make sure you are calling `bind()` *after* `setsockopt()` for this option.

Answer (score 2):

Another thing that can cause this to fail is doing it too late, it seems that on Linux at least it must be done before the socket is bound.